# Load a page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to know about the error happened during inserting the html code in the page this is my jquery code :

```
        var html = $.ajax({
            url: good.aspx,//in the local domain
            //complete: hideBlocker,
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        $("#HomeView").hide();
        $("#ContentView").html(html); //in this line it gives me script error
        $("#ContentView").show("fast");
```

the error says : SCRIPT5007: 'undefined' is null or not an object
the stop line is : var count = theForm.elements.length;

debugger is Microsoft internet explorer 9.0 beta

Comment: What is `mp`? Is it a url on another domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "good.aspx",
   data: "foo=bar&fooo=baz",
   success: function(msg){
     $('#HomeView').hide();
     $('#ContentView').html(msg);
     $('#ContentView').show('fast');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback function for the `complete` event:

```
$.get(
  'good.aspx',
  function (data) {
    $('#HomeView').hide();
    $('#ContentView').html(data);
    $('#ContentView').show('fast');
  }
);
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Could you provide more details?